# Optimization of ray triangle intersection algorithm in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing application that loads an STL file via the numpy-stl library and renders an image of it.

For rendering the final image I need to find the intersection point of a ray and a triangle in the mesh

I already implemented [Möller–Trumbore intersection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm) in numpy but performance is really bad with bigger models.

```
import numpy as np

#Loading the model via file
self.temp_mesh = Mesh.from_file("test.stl")

def intersectionRayModel(self, rayStart, rayEnd):
    w = rayEnd - rayStart
    w /= np.linalg.norm(w)

    data = self.temp_mesh

    counter = 0
    for tri in data.vectors+self.pos:
        b = [.0, .0, .0]

        e1 = tri[1]
        e1 -= tri[0]
        e2 = tri[2]
        e2 -= tri[0]

        n = self.temp_mesh.normals[counter]

        q = np.cross(w, e2)
        a = np.dot(e1, q)

        counter += 1
        if (np.dot(n, w) >= .0) or (abs(a) <= .0001):
            continue

        s = np.array(rayStart)
        s -= tri[0]
        s /= a

        r = np.cross(s, e1)
        b[0] = np.dot(s, q)
        b[1] = np.dot(r, w)
        b[2] = 1.0 - b[0] - b[1]

        if (b[0] < .0) or (b[1] < .0) or (b[2] < .0):
            continue

        t = np.dot(e2, r)
        if t >= .0:
            point = rayStart + t*w
            return True, point
        else:
            continue

    return False, None
```

I think a for loop is really bad here, but I was unable to find a way to get rid of it.

Comment: I think simply iterating over all triangles is more problematic: usually they use a grid, k-d tree or binary search tree.

Comment: Furthermore your algorithm is wrong in the sense that if you detect a collision, that does **not** guarantee that it is the **first one**, you should loop over **all** triangles until you found the first hit.

Comment: Finally note that OpenGL actually supports a cursor hit test: in that case openGL renders the screen, but uses triangle IDs instead of colors, you then only need to get the correct id from the "virtual" screen.

Comment: You right in point that I find only first hit in triangle order not first hit from rayStart. I was curious if anybody can show me some easy way how to rewrite a big for loop by numpy. In future I want to use python and numpy for work with bigger data in statistical calculations. And I thought that it would be understandable example for me and still solve this problem :-)

Comment: i feel that this would be better suited for code review